# Extract Values from the String Variable

Tags: java

```
String str=(37.028994, 35.26719589999993);
```

I have to retrieve these in separate variables.Can any one help to get those values?

For example, output should be of the following type.

```
a=37.028994
b=35.26719589999993
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: What a strange form of `String` representation. Will it be compiled?

Comment: Did you mean `"(37.028994, 35.26719589999993)"` or `"37.028994, 35.26719589999993"` or what?

Comment: i mean (37.028994, 35.26719589999993)

Comment: (37.028994, 35.26719589999993) is not a string, "(37.028994, 35.26719589999993)" would be

Comment: I don't know if this would be relavent but I think you should use a map for this

Answer (score 5):

```
    String str="(37.028994, 35.26719589999993)";
    str = str.substring(str.indexOf("(")+1 , str.indexOf(")"));
    String[] s = str.split(",");
    double a = Double.parseDouble(s[0]);
    double b = Double.parseDouble(s[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant this: `String str = "37.028994, 35.26719589999993";`

For which, you can use the `str.split(",");` method, and then do a `Double.parseDouble()` on the each element of the array of the split strings.

Answer (score 1):

First off, you need a pass in a String in the fist place...so I would assume the code should be:

```
String str="37.028994,35.26719589999993";
```

Then you can use `String.split(",")` to return an array of strings:

```
String[] splits = str.split(",");
```

Now do what you like with the array.

Answer (score 0):

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile ("\\d+\\.\\d+").matcher (str);
m.find ();
double a = Double.parseDouble (m.group ());
m.find ();
double b = Double.parseDouble (m.group ());
```

Comment: Watch out, you're assigning a double to a string.

Comment: Seems unnecessarily complicated (regex and such), Achintya Jha's answer is much more to the point.

Comment: It was not obvious whether brackets are part of string or not and what is separator in general case.  Jha's answer leaves extra space in second part which, fortunately, does not break parseDouble.